# jQuery when done not waiting for all deferreds to resolve

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have several Backbone.js models that I want to fetch, and then call a callback function when all the fetches are done. One model must be fetched before the others to get the id off of it.  What I have now is like:

```
doFetch: (model) ->
    model.set('first_model_id', @firstModel.get('id'))
    model.fetch()

doAsyncStuff: (callbackFn) ->
    $.when(
        @firstModel.fetch()
    ).done( =>
        $.when(
            @doFetch @secondModel,
            @doFetch @thirdModel
        ).done( =>
           callbackFn()
        )
    )
```

The problem is callbackFn is being called before the @secondModel and @thirdModel fetches are resolved.  If I assign the result of one of the doFetch calls to a local var and look at its state before calling callbackFn it usually is 'resolved' but sometimes is still 'pending'.  Why is the inner when/done not waiting for all those calls to resolve?

Comment: I don't know coffeescript, but, when i convert that script to js, i'm seeing something odd. Your inner when is written like this: `$.when(_this.doFetch(_this.secondModel, _this.doFetch(_this.thirdModel))).done(function() {` which doesn't look like the format that you intended. Note how the dofetch for third model is inside the call to the second model. This results in the inner when only waiting for the second to finish, not the third. Go Go Coffeescript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're syntax for the inner when is off, it's causing the third doFetch to be done as a 2nd parameter to the second. rewriting it this way seems to solve it. I also switched to .then as i think it makes for cleaner code in this case.

```
doFetch: (model) ->
    model.set('first_model_id', @firstModel.get('id'))
    model.fetch()

doAsyncStuff: (callbackFn) ->
    $.when(
        @firstModel.fetch()
    ).then( =>
        $.when(
            @doFetch @secondModel
            @doFetch @thirdModel
        )
    ).done( =>
        callbackFn()
    )
```

I just removed the comma after `@doFetch @secondModel`